Can I bring 5 kg rice and 3 kg lentils and other Indian items from Bangalore to Bordeaux?
My fiance is studying in France and I intend to visit her during Christmas. In Bordeaux, the rice and lentil price is very high, so I want to help her by bringing some items as listed below:

Rice: 5 kg
Lentils: 3 kg
Ghee: 250 g
Kaku barfi: 200 g
Malabar parota (ready to cook)
Black pepper powder

And some basic medicines like

Moov/volini (analgesic)
Abzorb powder(2 pieces)
Betadine ointment

I have booked my ticket on Air France. Can anybody help me with which items I can bring or not?

Posted as an other account:
Thanks everybody for the to-the-point answers... I have got my answers!

Will all the products be commercially packaged? The ghee is not allowed AFAIK

Important is also that you have the original receipt to show what you paid for the goods.

@MarkJohnson The monetary value of these goods is well under the EU's €430 limit.

As noted in the answers, you can bring some but not all of these goods. But bringing goods from the other side of the world that are readily available in France can trigger suspicion. You might be stuck in customs for longer than you'd like, if they're going to test everything for drugs.

@ItalianPhilosopher Sometimes the 'ethnic aisle' in a supermarket has cheaper goods by weight than the equivalent own-brand goods in the same supermarket.

Bring 30 Euro and buy her a 20 kg bag of rice in the supermarket: https://www.carrefour.fr/p/riz-long-parfume-premium-cambodge-royal-umbrella-8847102341561?t=2150 Save your packing space for stuff that you can't actually get in France.

Make sure everything that you put in your baggage that you declare on any forms/landing cards on arrival, and if asked mention everything. Attempting to not declare certain items can be a criminal offence, but by declaring items you should get away with a warning

@Marianne013 thanks that's a great advice

This question is similar to: Take groceries in checked luggage. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is somewhat ironic that rice and lentils are among the cheapest food items one can buy. Usually, customs questions concern heavily taxed and valuable articles like alcohol, cigarettes or jewellery. But rice and lentils!?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica There are so MANY questions about carrying rice from country X to country Y. One would think that no one has ever heard of rice being exported and imported.

A number of countries ban the importation of unprocessed foodstuffs for biosecurity reasons. They don't want exotic pests & diseases in their countries as this could negatively impact the health of its citizens or compromise their own farm based food production. You may think your food is clean, disease & pest free, but other countries may not. Some countries even have sniffer dogs at airports to detect food brought in by airline passengers. If such passengers are caught they face confiscation of the food, fines & possible deportation.

@shoover for some Japan/India anecdata: 5 kg of basmati rice could cost around 400-500 INR (~700-900 JPY). 5 kg of basmati rice typically costs over 2500 JPY in Tokyo. That's a 200% increase. Most Indians would find that hard to swallow. And when I buy an international ticket to Tokyo from Mumbai, I usually get 46kg of baggage allowance, and in practice I often have way more than 5 kg to spare. If it it were legal, you bet I'd be bringing all the rice I could. And that's for basmati, which is pretty well-known and easily available. For more obscure varieties...

@MarkJohnson Note that that "original" may not mean very much in some countries. In France it can be a handwritten paper as well as a printout of a MS Word document, or a scan of the latter sent by email. In Poland there is no concept of "original", everything is at best a printout from a central repository (you can not have a paper version at all)

No, you cannot bring that much. europa.eu:

If you travel to the EU from a non-EU country, you are not allowed to bring any meat or dairy products with you.

This means you cannot bring any ghee (clarified butter).
Kaju barfi (cashew candy) also usually contains ghee, but since it's in a cooked product this is probably OK.

Products other than those described above which do not contain meat or milk (e.g. honey)
Amount per person 2kg

So you can bring up to 2kg of rice or lentils, but definitely not 8kg.
That said, you can buy basmati rice at Carrefour for €2.50/kg and certainly less in bulk or at specialty retailers, so this hardly seems like it's worth the effort.

Indeed, if they have gotten a round-trip plane ticket from far away—likely the vicinity of India given the foods and the names of the medications—they very likely are paying something like 500+ euro to begin with. 30 euro in bulk food on top of that is undoubtedly very expensive compared to prices in India, but should hopefully be affordable to someone who can afford the plane ticket.

(+1) The rules governing importing medicinal products to France indicate that the OP should have a personal prescription for Abzorb powders, IDK about the rest, they may be OK w/o paperwork if they’re OTC products.

@Traveller useful to mention that leaving or sharing the medication with the partner in France may violate additional laws (I'm not familiar with French law, for Germany the equivalent law would be AMG). While it's unlikely to be detected after the fact, if OP gets pulled over at customs and states their intentions, it may have negative consequences.

This is not correct, I have brought about 10kg of Rice into the EU from outside EU with no issues. In fact I even brought it in the carry on.

@VahidAmiri You can even bring 10 kg of cocaine in your carry on. You are not allowed to, but you can. And some succeed to..

Last time I traveled (from France) to India (Mysore), I looked at the 5kg rice bags sold in small stores or in supermarkets and did not find any gain in buying a bag there compared with the prices in France. The only deal (of interest to me) stands with specialty teas like Daerjeelings where the difference often is by a factor of four.

(shifting from a comment to an answer)
Frameshift:  this is quite possibly not necessary in the first place.
At least in big cities, you may very well be able to find stores catering to the diaspora.
If I google "bordeaux magasin indien alimentation" I find a number of "ethnic stores".  They seem to be clustered together, near the center of town from the looks of it.  Good opportunity to walk around, discover Bordeaux, and solve this differently.
Now, if it's anything like what I remember from living in Paris (and shopping at a Chinese supermarket in the 13th arrondissement). Or in Canada, where I live now, shopping at "ethnic stores", their prices are often much below "proper supermarkets".
So it pays to shop around, for general foods, and especially if you are looking for bulk and/or ethnic foods. Lots of people just care about getting good food without all the pomp and marketing costs that regular supermarkets saddle us with.
p.s.  Not all such stores are cheaper.  For example, where I live, Japanese specialty stores are often, not always, quite expensive and carry mostly high-end packaged branded goods from home.  Mexican ones are often tiny and don't carry all that much.  Sometimes you just have to visit to see if you are getting value or novelty-for-tourists.
But Chinese and Indian stores are usually better bets.
p.s. In any case, they feel a little bit like getting out of town which is why I like to shop in those places.

One slight consideration, at least in my experience, while specialist stores can be far cheaper than other supermarkets (quite a lot of stuff is marked up at least 2-3x in normal supermarkets around me), they still tend to be quite a lot more expensive than buying in the country of origin, which I expect is still a consideration for the op, but if they haven't found any local specialist stores, definately seek them out, many of them are small family run shops who may even be willing to import/order specific brands/products for regular customers.

As an expat who used to live in Singapore. It was difficult to get the rice I am familiar with in local stores. Then I found the stores run by my people. I was able to get rice in bulk for real cheap. Also, Mustafa in SG - you will get anything Indian in there. Check with people from your ethnic background who are living there long term (5+ years). They will definitely know the tricks.


Moov

If I got it right from their web page, this is based on diclofenac, which is widely used in France (Voltarène and many generics). They are reimbursed by social security when prescribed by a doctor. Since your fiancée is a student, she will have a mutuelle (extra insurance) which will cover 100% of the costs.

Abzorb

It looks like it is clotrimazole. This is available in France but not reimbursed.

Betadine

Widely available in France. Reimbursed.
Notes:

All the above drugs are also available OTC
I would highly recommend not to self-medicate but to check with a doctor.


OP didn't ask for health advice btw.

@VahidAmiri Yes I know and this was not the core of my answer. The note at the end is to make sure that someone makes good use of the French healthcare system to, possibly, get medication more adapted to a specific case. We have a very generous healthcare system and someone coming in may not be completely aware of that and might avoid getting advice because of the costs. I faced this with people coming from all over the world so that was a "just in case" message.

@VahidAmiri I thought the health question was implicit because the OP was asking about importing drugs to treat health conditions.

Diclofenac and Betadine are kind of OTC medication in India. No need for prescription. These are found in first aid boxes, which are supposed to be used by non-medical people.

@AnishSheela I just checked with the national drugs registry and all of them are also available OTC. I updated my answer with that.
